# how to convert date in English and French

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to store formatted display dates in my tables.  For example, I have a date as 20150621 and I want it as June 21, 2015 and 21 juin 2015 (for French).

I have a  query: `convert(varchar(12),cast([datecolumn]) as datetime),107)`

This outputs: Jun 21,2015 , but I need June 21,2015 and also French date.

I am using Sql 2005, so format doesn`t work in it.

Comment: and my date column is varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write as:

```
    SELECT DATENAME(MM, CAST([datecolumn] AS DATETIME))
       + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107), 9) 
       AS [Month DD, YYYY]
from test

Go

SET LANGUAGE French
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),CAST(datecolumn AS DATETIME),106) as [DD MON YYYY]
from test
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6bdc8/8)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks deepshikha , i am trying to do this in SQL 2005 SET LANGUAGE French
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),CAST(datecolumn AS DATETIME),106) as [DD MON YYYY] ..... but giving me error that its not proper format in SQL 2005

Comment: not proper format??  it can be two things either French is not installed : check the results for `select * from sys.syslanguages` or as date has been stored as varchar, there might be a column which is in incorrect format

Comment: yes the date is in format like 20150421 , and its a varchar column , that why i am doing cast as datetime

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Language` to French and then run your query. Something like this

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATETIME),107)

SET LANGUAGE French
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATETIME),107)
```

Comment: Thanks ughai , but do you know if this function works on 2005 edition

Comment: yes it will work. check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). you can try my sample query  as well

Comment: Thanks ughai , it worked for french , awesome i appriciate , but not working for english any comments ....