# How to convert non-English date string to English format using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to convert a non-English date to English format in SQL
For instance  Mittwoch April  17 2019, this to English.
This is German and desired output is in English format.
The source format can be anything, so I am looking for a generic solution.
any idea?

Comment: did you look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773908/how-to-convert-date-in-english-and-french

Comment: if the source format can be *anything*, that could mean you have a date like `'05-06-07'`. Without knowing the format, what is the value of that date: 5 June 2007, 6 May 2007, 7 June 2005, or 6 July 2005? (Hint, what ever answer you choose, it's wrong). Without knowing the format that a string representation of a date is using, it is useless to you.

Comment: It is impossible to have a generic solution that converts anything. First of all, if only numbers are used for day, month and year, then you have the problem that the order is culture specific. Secondly, good luck covering an "anything" like this: "de twintigste rond deze tijd volgend jaar". At the very least, you need syntax rules.

Comment: by anything I meant, Month name can be in format like -> April or Aprile or Avril or Kwiecień. So the date can be like  "April 17 2019" or "Aprile 17 2019" or "Avril 17 2019" or "Kwiecień 17 2019"
The source is an order XML generated from e-commerce site, which can be from any region :)
Anyways, as a temporary solution, I created a config table to store the month name mapping and then used it to replace the text in the string.